# Reading and writing files in python 3

Tags: python, file

```
import os.path

endofprogram=False
try:

   filename1=input("Enter input file: ")
   filename2=input("Enter output file: ")

   while os.path.isfile(filename2):
       filename2=input("File Exists! Enter new name for output file: ") 

except IOError:
   print("Error opening file - End of program")
   endofprogram=True

if(endofprogram == False):
   infile=open(filename1, "r")
   content=infile.read()
   lines=[]
   words=[]

   lines=content.split('\n')
   print("Total animals=",len(lines))
```

I've been working on this program having to do with files for ages now. I have a file:

```
#color     size    flesh     class
brown     large    hard      safe
green     large    hard      safe
red       large    soft      dangerous
green     large    soft      safe


red       small    hard      safe
red       small    hard      safe
brown     small    hard      safe
green     small    soft      dangerous
green     small    hard      dangerous
red       large    hard      safe
brown     large    soft      safe
green     small    soft      dangerous
red       small    soft      safe
red       large    hard      dangerous
red       small    hard      safe
green     small    hard      dangerous
```

And I'm supposed to answer the following questions:

- Total number of animals?
- Total number of dangerous animals?
- Number of large animals that are safe?

So far, I can print out the total number of animals but it includes the blank spaces along with the comment line which I don't want. Currently for total number of animals, what gets printed is 19 when it should be 16. And I have no idea where to begin with the two questions after that.

Comment: Please fix missing colons and indentation.

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Fixed it.

Comment: @lfhfsfhjsf Rather than defining your own end of program and own errors use the available ones via os. Get familar with using std err and try and catch for exceptions. 'code' try:   etc etc etc then                                     except OSError as e:
      print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should process the file line by line, that would be easier than reading the whole file, something like:

```
infile = open('entrada', 'r')

animals = 0
safe_animals = 0
dangerous_animals = 0

for line in infile:
    line_components = line.strip().split()
    if line_components:
        animals += 1

        if line_components[3] == 'dangerous':
            dangerous_animals += 1
        elif line_components[3] == 'safe' and line_components[1] == 'large':
            safe_animals += 1

print "%i animals" % animals
print "%i safe animals" % safe_animals
print "%i dangerous animals" % dangerous_animals
```

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway you can help me do the other part of the question? Where I have to find the total number of dangerous animals and number of animals that are safe.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. What I meant to say is I have to find the number of dangerous animals and the number of **large** animals that are **safe**

Comment: Well, you have all the information about each animal in the `line_components` list, so you can easily check if it's large and safe. However I've just edited the code.

Comment: Can you please mark this as the answer for the question? It's the tick symbol under the score at the left.

Answer (score 1):

Here a quite verbose way of doing it:

```
color, size, flesh, clas = 0, 1, 2, 3 #column index
animals = []
with open ('animals.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] in '#\n': continue
        animals.append(line.split())
print(animals)
print(len(animals))
print(sum(1 for animal in animals if animal[clas] == 'dangerous'))
print(sum(1 for animal in animals if animal[clas] == 'safe' and animal[size] == 'large'))
```

Explanation: Iterate over all lines. If the line is empty or a comment, skip it. Otherwise split the line and add it to all animals. Each animal is a list of four elements (therefore the column indices in the first line). Now just filter and count the matching animals.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the content all at once, and then splitting `content`, you might want to you use the readlines() method for file objects, like so:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
```

Then you can do some filtering, to remove commented and / or blank lines before parsing the columns.

An example would be the the list comprehension `lines = [line for line in lines if len(line.strip()) > 0]`. You can do something similar to get rid of the commented line(s).

The `split` method would be more appropriate for actually parsing each individual line.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a database or yaml or json to hold your data ?

A lot nice than plain text files and easier to parse/query.

json    http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html
pyYaml  http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML